# Javascript/jQuery bar chart pluign with draggable data

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts

I have been tasked with creating a bar chart generator with the following requirements:

- Fields to enter values to generate the chart
- Once chart has been generated, the bars can be dragged/resized

I have had a good search and found a few options such as JS Charts, but I can't find a plugin that is free, or offers the dragging I need. If anybody has any suggestions it would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to plot time data in the chart, then you will need a gantt like the **RadiantQ  jQuery Gantt** Package. It supports very interactive dragging and resizing among other things. It's not free, but is totally worth it for the features that it provides.

For more details visit it's features page http://radiantq.com/jquery-gantt-package-features/. and look it in action at the [live demo](http://demos.radiantq.com/jQueryGanttDemo/demo.htm).